# Is there any way to do select on top of WITH clause in a SQL Server CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have a properly working CTE query. I'm using this query in an application which does select on top of it and giving error

> Incorrect syntax near WITH

Is there any way I can do select on top of WITH?

```
select(columns) from
(WITH CTE AS(
     #code
))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support this kind of syntax **[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d908c140a3bd9e3d3f4f4c63a84d806f)**. You need to rewrite your query:

```
WITH CTE AS(
     #code
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

Or wrap you query with view and select from it instead.

Comment: My query works fine when executed. Problem here is the application which I don't have control over and does a select on top my query.

Comment: @gdanton  I would create view on top of CTE and allow application to query view instead.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You declare the CTE first, then you select from it in the following statement

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
 select 1 AS col
)
SELECT col
FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the with Clause and do

```
select col1, col2, col3 from
(select col1, col2, col3 from table  ) as CTE
```

only drawback is that the derived table can be used only once not like a true CTE